# BeautifulSoup - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributes

I'm having an issue with using the `.findAll` attribute. when I run the code below, it says object has no attribute `findAll`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

url = 'https://csgostash.com/weapon/Butterfly+Knife'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id="row")

job_elems = results.findAll('section', class_="well result-box nomargin")
for job_elem in job_elems:
    title_elem = jobelem.find('h3', class_='a')
    print(title_elem.text.strip())
```

Error message

> job_elems = results.findAll('section', class_="well result-box nomargin")
>       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Comment: It's apparent that `soup.find(id="row")` returned `None`, so you should find out why that is.

Comment: Also change `findAll` to `find_all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the HTML for the page you're trying to scrape, it's apparent that no elements have `id="row"`; hence, you get the error that you cannot call `findAll` on `None`.

You could skip that step and go straight to finding `'div'` (instead of `'section'`) elements with `class_='well result-box nomargin'`:

```
job_elems = soup.find_all('div', class_="well result-box nomargin")             
for job_elem in job_elems:                                                      
    title_elem = job_elem.find('a')                                             
    if title_elem:                                                              
        print(title_elem.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
★ (Vanilla)
Marble Fade
Doppler
Tiger Tooth
Damascus Steel
Ultraviolet
Rust Coat
Fade
Slaughter
Crimson Web
Night
Case Hardened
Blue Steel
Boreal Forest
Stained
Forest DDPAT
Urban Masked
Scorched
Safari Mesh
```

Note that there are several mistakes in your code, including `jobelem` instead of `job_elem`. You also attempt to get the text of the `h3` element, though you are actually looking for the `a` element nested inside that.